# How to count the number of promises that have failed?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small Javascript application that uses an API from [pokeapi.co](https://www.pokeapi.co). Basically, it is supposed to fetch a few datas from the API and then display them on an HTML page. Here is the main part of the code :

```
const searchInput= document.querySelector(".recherche-poke input");
let allPokemon= [];
let tableauFin= [];
const listePoke= document.querySelector('.liste-poke');

function fetchPokemonBase(){
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=75")
        .then(reponse => reponse.json())
        .then((allPoke) =>{
            allPoke.results.forEach((pokemon) =>{
                fetchPokemonComplet(pokemon);
            })
        })
}

fetchPokemonBase();

function fetchPokemonComplet(pokemon){
    let objPokemonFull = {};
    let url = pokemon.url;
    let nameP = pokemon.name;

    fetch(url)
        .then(reponse => reponse.json())
        .then((pokeData) => {
            objPokemonFull.pic = pokeData.sprites.front_default;
            objPokemonFull.type = pokeData.types[0].type.name;
            objPokemonFull.id = pokeData.id;

            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${nameP}`)
                .then(reponse => reponse.json())
                .then((pokeData) => {
                    objPokemonFull.name= pokeData.names[4].name;
                    allPokemon.push(objPokemonFull);

                    if(allPokemon.length === 75){
                        tableauFin= allPokemon.sort((a, b) => {
                            return a.id - b.id;
                        }).slice(0, 21);

                        createCard(tableauFin);
                    }
                })
        });
}

function createCard(arr){
    for(let i= 0; i< arr.length; i++){
        console.log(i + '\n');

        const carte= document.createElement("li");
        const txtCarte= document.createElement('h5');
        txtCarte.innerText= arr[i].name;
        const idCarte= document.createElement('p');
        idCarte.innerText= `ID# ${arr[i].id}`;
        const imgCarte= document.createElement('img');
        imgCarte.src= arr[i].pic;

        carte.appendChild(imgCarte);
        carte.appendChild(txtCarte);
        carte.appendChild(idCarte);

        listePoke.appendChild(carte);
    }
}
```

Here's what the code does : it gather a list of 75 pokemons from the pokeapi API. Then it fetches the data about each pokemon from the same site and stores each data into one element of the `allPokemon` array, when the length of this array reaches 75, we begin to create the HTML elements to display the data.

The ambigious part here is :

```
if(allPokemon.length === 75){
    tableauFin= allPokemon.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.id - b.id;
        }).slice(0, 21);
    
   createCard(tableauFin);
  }
```

This code works but only when none of the requests fail. Otherwise, the length of the array `allPokemon` never reaches 75 and the rest of the code won't be executed. When I run the code, I run on [XHR GET errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZYcA.png) and the script stops before displaying the datas and it's (I think) what caused one of the promises to [fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3vqQ.png). I tried things like `if(allPokemon.length === 74)` (if I have one error, for example) and the code works just fine but that is surely not the solution.

Is there a way for me to "count" the errors I get from my requests so that I can do something like `if(allPokemon.length === 75 - errorsCount)` or maybe there is a smarter way to write my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use promise.catch() to increment a global variable

Comment: I've tried using `.catch((error)=>{console.log(error); err+= 1})` on each one of the `fetch()` but it didn't work. `err` always stays on 0 and no log on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use promise all for this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
function fetchPokemonBase(){
    const promises = []

    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=75")
        .then(reponse => reponse.json())
        .then((allPoke) =>{
            allPoke.results.forEach((pokemon) =>{
                promises.push(fetchPokemonComplet(pokemon).catch(error => console.error(error)));
            })
        })
        .then(() => {
          Promise.all(promises)
            .then(() => {
              tableauFin= allPokemon.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.id - b.id;
              }).slice(0, 21);

              createCard(tableauFin);
            })
        })
}

fetchPokemonBase();
let counter = 0
function fetchPokemonComplet(pokemon){
    let objPokemonFull = {};
    let url = pokemon.url;
    let nameP = pokemon.name;
    return fetch(url)
    .then(reponse => reponse.json())
    .then((pokeData) => {
            counter++;
            objPokemonFull.pic = pokeData.sprites.front_default;
            objPokemonFull.type = pokeData.types[0].type.name;
            objPokemonFull.id = pokeData.id;
            return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${nameP}`)
                .then(reponse => reponse.json())
                .then((pokeData) => {
                    objPokemonFull.name= pokeData.names[4].name;
                    allPokemon.push(objPokemonFull);

                })
        });
}
```

So what you do is, instead of executing the fetch in the foreach, we push each fetch to an array of promises. Then we use the promise.all to execute them, and for each promise we catch the errors. So if one fails, the next promise will just continue.

With this code we push every fetch for the individual pokemons to an array:

```
promises.push(fetchPokemonComplet(pokemon).catch(error => console.error(error)));
```

Then we have an array of promises, which are the fetches to the server.
With the following code we execute these promises.

```
Promise.all(promises)
                .then(() => {
                  tableauFin= allPokemon.sort((a, b) => {
                    return a.id - b.id;
                  }).slice(0, 21);
    
                  createCard(tableauFin);
                })
```

the then on promise.all will be executed when all the promises are done.
And since we catch on every individual promise we don't have to worry about that.
And we don't care about the length and don't have to keep count.
Let me know if it works, or need any help.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the answer ! It worked ! The first time I launched it, I got some duplicates though, I don't know why. I launched it a second time and it runs just fine. I checked `counter` on the console and it showed 74. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, and you don't have to worry about the count!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you will receive a list of between 0 and 75 pokemons from the first API call. Then, you fetch each one, however many it returned, up to 75 entries.

So, I think you want to just make sure your list isn't empty:
`if(allPokemon.length > 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that would actually execute the code as soon as the first element get pushed into `allPokemon` and repeat each time anew element is added.